# Yii2 Youtube Analytics get channel report - Required Error Getting

Tags: php, curl, youtube-api, yii2-advanced-app, youtube-data-api

Using google SDK I am getting the youtube channel id access_token successfully, but I want more details from youtube channel, for that, am passing the access token, developer key via Curl but am getting the following error

```
linslin\yii2\curl\Curl Object
(
 [response] => {
 "error": {
 "code": 400,
"message": "Required",
"errors": [
  {
    "message": "Required",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required"
  }
]
}
}
```

Here below my controller Action Code.,

```
   $curl = new curl\Curl();
        $response = 
                $curl->setGetParams([
                    'metrics' => 'views,averageViewPercentage,comments,likes,dislikes',
                    'key' => $developer_key,  
                    'channel' => 'MINE',                          
                    'startDate' => '2014-05-01',                          
                    'endDate' => '2018-07-26',                          
                    'access_token' => $accessToken

                ])
                ->setHeaders([
                             'access_token' => 
              // $accessToken    commented this
                 ])

          ->get('https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports');
   print_r($result); exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer and it worked!...
Have to pass "Bearer" in access token like below,

```
 ->setHeaders([
                    'authorization' => "Bearer $accessToken",
                    'Content-Type' => "application/json"
                 ])
```